# How to turn a returned object into a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using an input that takes a number that a user enters and converts it to a dollar amount when the blur event fires.

The issue I am having is that the browser seems to keep previously submitted values intact with their dollar signs. So if the user selects a previously entered value of '$25000' from the drop down list, when the blur event fires again it adds in the '$' so I get '$$25000'

In order to stop this, i've made an adjustment to the string value if it contains 2 '$'s on blur:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="$5,000" id="dollar-amount-goal" />
```

Javascript:

```
var valueOnBlur = $('#dollar-amount-goal').val();

if(valueOnBlur.charAt(1) === '$'){
    valueOnBlur = $('#dollar-amount-goal').val(valueOnBlur.substr(1));
}

console.log(typeof( valueOnBlur ));
```

The result of the typeof statement above when the string checking is run is 'object'. any time after it comes out as 'string' (which is what I want).

My question: How do I make the `"valueOnBlur = $('#dollar-amount-goal').val(valueOnBlur.substr(1));"` statement return a string when it's run?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
valueOnBlur = $('#dollar-amount-goal').val(valueOnBlur.substr(1));
```

To this:

```
valueOnBlur = $('#dollar-amount-goal').val(valueOnBlur.substr(1)).val();
```

You want the value of the `$('#dollar-amount-goal')` and not the jQuery object that `$('#dollar-amount-goal')` will return

Comment: @hyperdouche Then click the green arrow next to the answer

Comment: will do mate, you were so quick with the answer that I still have to wait 6 mins :) Cheers.

Comment: There's no need to retrieve the value from the textfield again. Just use `valueOnBlur = valueOnBlur.substr(1);`